# git stage all files that are already tracked and have a certain extension

Tags: git

As the title says: Is it somehow possible in git to...

- ...stage all files that are already under version control...
- ...and have a certain file extension?

The use case is a repo where I often have files that remain untracked (changes too fast to add them to gitignore) and I have some binary data files that I don't want and need to commit after each modification, only occasionally.

So basically I often want to say: **"Hey git, stage all already tracked files with extension *.xyz".**

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
git add -u '*.xyz'
```

*( thanks to UnbearableLightness for the insight about* `-u` *)*

( and mind the quotes )

Comment: Aw... right it does. Adding a disclaimer, thanks for your vigilance.